# How to get root node error value from rpart printcp function?

Tags: r, rpart

From `rpart` package, it is possible to get following output from `printcp` function. But how to extract the root node error value?

```
Classification tree:
rpart(formula = survived ~ ., data = ptitanic, control = rpart.control(cp = 1e-04))

#Variables actually used in tree construction:
#[1] age    parch  pclass sex    sibsp 

#Root node error: 500/1309 = 0.38

#n= 1309 

 #     CP nsplit rel error xerror  xstd
 #1 0.4240      0      1.00   1.00 0.035
 #2 0.0210      1      0.58   0.58 0.030
 #3 0.0150      3      0.53   0.57 0.030
 #4 0.0113      5      0.50   0.57 0.030
 #5 0.0026      9      0.46   0.53 0.029
 #6 0.0020     16      0.44   0.53 0.029
 #7 0.0001     18      0.44   0.53 0.029
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the root error value from the `frame` component of your `fit` via:

```
 fit$frame[1, 'dev']/fit$frame[1, 'n']
```

or the `yval2.V5` entry in the 1st row of `fit$frame`.